# Add a meta description for a custom post type archive in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, custom-post-type, yoast

Here's my issue :
I have a WordPress site where I created a custom post type (named "`collections`") with an article for each collection.
I'd like to add a meta description to the archive page of the custom post type

```
www.thesitename.com/collections
```

I have tried with this bit in `header.php` :

```
<?php
if (is_category('collections'))
{
    ?> 
    <meta name="description" content="the description">
<?php } ?>
```

but there's nothing in the source code...
I have looked everywhere in Yoast SEO but I can't find a solution, not even on google. 
Do you have ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want to check `post_type` archive page then you have to use
>   [`is_post_type_archive()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) and if you want to check the archive page of
>   custom `post_type` category then you have to use [`is_tax()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax)

```
if (is_post_type_archive('collections'))
{
    echo 'This is the collections post_type archive page';
}
```

Addition info but not directly related to your question.

```
if (is_tax('collections_cat', 'cat-1'))//<-- Replace it with your taxonomy, term name
{
    echo 'This is the collections post_type, category cat 1 archive page';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I put is_post_type_archive and it's works ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is written in `PHP`, which means that `HTML` like that will not work by itself. It is for this reason that in most tracking codes are established by including something along the lines of `<?php include_once("analytics.php"); ?>`

In your case, you would have to `echo` any HTML elements like this. Like so:

```
  <?php if (is_category('collections')) {

    echo"<meta name='description' content='the description'>";

     }
  ?>
```